# Realtime API hosting recommendations and suggestions for architecture design

Tags: backend, devops, saas, paas, iaas

Does anyone have any good realtime IaaS / PaaS / SaaS / FaaS recommendations?

I've got a live native mobile app which is currently on a Firebase/Firestore backend. However, as some of you may know, Firebase's ability to accommodate complex queries can be quite limited. This means that as we scale our functionality upwards, we're facing more problems, and so we're now looking to move. There seems to be a lot of options for cloud hosting, infrastructure, etc.

I've tried my best to do my own research, looking through forums, youtube, purchasing udemy courses, and also playing around with some services such as AWS and Heroku. But with so many options, many being microservices, I'm finding it extremely easy to get bogged down in what is the right choice, or how to connect the right services together to make a realtime API that is cost-efficient, low-latency, and connects to my native iOS/Android Clients.

As I imagine I'm not the only developer with shockingly non-existent skills in devOps, I thought this would make for a more human form of research and a great/informative post for others looking to build out their own custom, realtime, backend architecture. I'll add specifics of my own efforts in a comment below.

Any tips?

Comment: For my situation specifically, I want to migrate to a PostgreSQL DB, with middleware that contects to my clients. Given that we were on Firebase/Functions before (which is serverless), I wanted to go for that again. Serverless is also considered as we are early in building a social network (~500 users) which can have unpredictable traffic.  I've managed to set up and deploy a test CRUD API on Node. I've also set up a streaming API on localhost. I'm just confused on how to deploy a serverless streaming API, given data limits? Serverless isn't the be-all-end-all btw! It's just what I'm used to.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.

Comment: RE attempts so far: I tried AWS Amplify/AppSync, with a Serverless Aurora PostgreSQL backend, but it had a common (unanswered) issue, so I assume that even though Aurora now supports psql, Amplify doesn't. I then tried the same but with Aurora serverless MySQL as a backend. But to no avail, Amplify kept connecting me with DynamoDB. I then tried Heroku, but data seemed to be publicly exposed, I wasn't sure how to make a solid back-and-forth flow between Heroku and my client, and connections only stay open for 55s so it seemed like perhaps not the best choice for streaming connections.